# How to add .so file in Android.mk file?

Tags: android, android-source, .so, android-make

I am importing a .aar file as a dependency in my android project and have added this to Android.mk file.

Now internally this file has dependency on some **.so** files which its not able to pick up automatically.

So I copied all the dependent **.so** files under the below structure,

```
     app --> libs --> arm64-v8a --> test.so 
              |
              |   --> x86 --> test.so
```

And now I tried several combination of below config in Android.mk file, but the above test.so file is not getting added to the apk generated after building.

.
.
.
.

```
    **include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    ifneq (,$(filter $(TARGET_ARCH_ABI), armeabi-v7a x86 arm64-v8a x86_64))
    LOCAL_MODULE := Some Name
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := sources/app/libs/$(TARGET_ARCH)/xyz.so  //Path of of my local .so file
    LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := SHARED_LIBRARIES
    include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)**
```

I tried lot of googling and also referred Android Xref, but unable to figure out what I am missing.

Any leads?

Answer (score 0):

LOCAL_PREBUILT_JNI_LIBS = libs/xxxx.so

See example:
https://github.com/ayufan-pine64/proprietary_vendor_google_atv/blob/master/atv/Android.mk

Comment: Yong, thanks for sharing this. But I assume here the .so files are being referred from a prebuilt apk? In my case I have a .aar module dependency which in turn dependent on .so files. But anyways I will give a try for the mentioned solution

Comment: @tejas have you solved your problem ? I have same issue with you but i have not solution yet.

Comment: @TuanPM The solution I figured out is push your apk and .so file to both /system/app/ folder and /system/lib64/ folder respectively. Just by installing this doesn't work

Comment: Why do ppl keep going down the path of deploying into system folders when clearly there must be a way to include the .so in the APK as it is done in Android Studio (I mean there is support for it)

Answer (score 0):

Best way to add shared library in Android.mk and making sure it will be part of system/lib or system/lib64 based of CPU ARCh is

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := AndroidMediaShell
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := app/$(LOCAL_MODULE).apk
LOCAL_PREBUILT_JNI_LIBS := lib/lib_example.so
LOCAL_MODULE_TARGET_ARCH := arm or arm64 or x86
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := PRESIGNED
LOCAL_OVERRIDES_PACKAGES :=
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```